# error TS1055: Type 'boolean' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using **Ionic 4**

I have a service **auth-guard** which returns boolean

```
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    public Auth: AuthService,
    public router: Router,
    private nav: NavController
  ) {
  }

  canActivate() {
    // if userValid is true and user is not authenticated,
    // probably access token has been expired,
    // refresh token
    if (!this.Auth.userValid()) {
      return this._cannotActivate();
    } else if (this.Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return this.Auth.refreshAuthToken().pipe(
        map(() => this.Auth.isAuthenticated() || this._cannotActivate())
      );
    }
  }

  private async _cannotActivate(): boolean {
    await this.nav.navigateRoot('/auth/login');
    return false;
  }
}
```

and using in routes module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: '.../admin-module', canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
];
```

But this gives error as

```
error TS1055: Type 'boolean' is not a valid async function return type in ES5/ES3 
because it does not refer to a Promise-compatible constructor value.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tried, but you can try this solution -

```
private _cannotActivate(): boolean {
  this.nav.navigateRoot('/auth/login').then(() => {
    return false;
  });
}
```

Or IMO navigation is not async in nature so you can omit `await` and simply return boolean value which will not throw any error probably like this -

```
private _cannotActivate(): boolean {
    this.nav.navigateRoot('/auth/login');
    return false;
  }
```